# Regular expressions

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

I have this assignment and I have to prove that
$$
  (b+aa^* b)+(b+aa^* b)(a+ba^* b)^* (a+ba^* b) = a^* b(a+ba^* a)b^* 
$$
How do I prove this?

What I have is this: 
$$\begin{align}
 \text{LHS} &= (b+aa^* b)(\varepsilon+(a+ba^* b)^* (a+ba^* b)) \\
  &= (b+aa^* b)(a+ba^* b)^* \\
  &= (\varepsilon+aa^* )b(a+ba^* b)^* \\
  &= a^* b(a+ba^* b)^* \\
\end{align}$$

but I don't know how to proceed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won’t be able to prove it, because it’s false. The string $b$ matches $\color{blue}b+aa^*b$, so it matches the left-hand side. It does not match the right-hand side, however: the shortest string that matches $a^*\color{blue}b(\color{blue}a+ba^*a)b^*$ is $ba$.

Or, since your algebra is correct, just notice that $n$ matches your $a^*\color{blue}b(a+ba^*b)^*$ but not the original right-hand side.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I got it!

Comment: @DarkBlueJenny: Excellent! You're welcome.